# An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException'

Tags: .net, entity-framework, ado.net

Additional information: Unable to determine the DbProviderFactory type for connection of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection'. Make sure that the ADO.NET provider is installed or registered in the application config.

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: the same code work in another machine

Comment: I don't understand what you're attempting to say with your comment. Could you please clarify?

Comment: the problem is not related to the code because  the same code work in another machine

Comment: if the app config is the same (and actually called by EF config), your problem is that the required EF provider (System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices) is not installed on your machine.

Comment: Try `install-package entityframework` in the nuget package manager console.